# Defining different URL for mobile devices

Tags: google-ads-api

I would like to make it so that mobile users are directed to a different URL than desktop users.

Where could I do that without having to define a completely new campaign?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a programming-related question, you can do so by means of the **Use a different final URL for mobile** setting in the **Ad URL options** section of any ad:

[image]